# Spring Kafka Idempotence Producer configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

For the native Java Kafka client, there is a Kafka configuration called, `enable.idempotence` and we can set it to be `true` to enable idempotence producer.

However, for Spring Kafka, I can't find similar idempotence property in `KafkaProperties` class.

So I am wondering, if I manually set in my Spring Kafka configuration file, whether this property will take effect or Spring will totally ignore this config for Spring Kafka?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to specify this property

**application.properties** You can use this property to specify any additional properties on producer

```
spring.kafka.producer.properties.*= # Additional producer-specific properties used to configure the client.
```

If you have any additional common config between Producer and Consumer

```
spring.kafka.properties.*= # Additional properties, common to producers and consumers, used to configure the client.
```

**Through Code** You can also override and customize the configs

```
 @Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {

   Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
   configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
    StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
      StringSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to add features that are not handled by Spring KafkaProperties, if you look at the documentation, you can do as the following:

```
Only a subset of the properties supported by Kafka are available directly through the KafkaProperties class. 
If you wish to configure the producer or consumer with additional properties that are not directly supported, use the following properties:

spring.kafka.properties.prop.one=first
spring.kafka.admin.properties.prop.two=second
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.prop.three=third
spring.kafka.producer.properties.prop.four=fourth
spring.kafka.streams.properties.prop.five=fifth
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-kafka-extra-props

Yannick

Answer (score 0):

You can find it with `ProducerConfig` as it is producer configuration. In order to enable this, you need to add below line in producerConfigs:

```
  Properties producerProperties = new Properties();
  producerProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
  producerProperties.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true);
```